# Adding custom page properties

Tags: sharepoint-online, metadata

I'd like to add some metadata to pages on my site.  It looks like 'page properties' is where I should be doing this but the only pair there is for "Name".

[image: screenshot]

I assume it's possible to add customer name/value pairs here but I can't see where to do it through the UI and my google fu is obviously failing me today.  Can anyone tell me where I add these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do this assuming your question is specific to page properties and nothing else.

Firstly - You can add a single line text column named "Customer" to the document library where your page resides.

Second - Managed Metadata Service (recommended way) - Using managed metadata SharePoint will give multitude of options with metadata and keywords thereby also improving search , content organization and navigation. You can see [here](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2009/12/managed-metadata-in-sharepoint-2010-key.html) how it works.

Comment: Thanks, sometimes it's just a case of knowing what to search for!

Answer (score 1):

Some extra info I discovered in case anyone else stumbles across this question later:

In Sharepoint Online (2010), you get to the Metadata editor by going to Site Settings > Site Administration > Term Store Management.  It's also available via the admin site under 'Term Store' in the main menu.

In order to edit the terms, you need to give yourself Admin rights for it (in the right hand pane of the term store).  This step confused be a bit since I was already logged in with an administrator account.

To get your newly created tags to appear when you edit properties on a page, you need to add the columns to the content type 'document'.  You do this through Site Settings > Galleries > Site Content Types and then select the 'document' item under the Document Content Types heading.